# How can I disable the window's 'x' button in OpenGL/C++/Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, glut

I need to make sure that the person using my tool follows a very strict flow, so closing the program is only permitted under certain conditions.  I'd like to disable the close button for a window.

Comment: How are you planning on disabling `kill(1)`/`xkill(1)`?

Comment: The person who will be using this tool isn't a tech-savvy person.  He hasn't a clue about the terminal (or how to terminate a program with it), but it's his instinct to close a program with the 'x' in the window border, which I need to prevent.

Comment: @Benjin: Have you considered... not using FreeGLUT, and instead using [something that gives you this kind of control](http://www.glfw.org/)?

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm an intern with Friday being my last day.  This is among a laundry list of things to finish in a single day.  I have neither the time nor the pull on the team to implement such a change.  Trust me, GLUT wouldn't be my first choice, either.